# Android webview: inject a function call to the onclick event of a checkbox

Tags: javascript, android, checkbox, webview

I have the following html code loaded in a webview:

```
<form>
    <input checked="true" id="myCheckBox" onchange=
    "location.href='/doSomething.html'" type=
    "checkbox">My Checkbox description
</form>
```

I can not modify this the html code because I'm not the owner of the web site. What I want to do is to receive in my Android app if the user clicks on the checkbox, and the value of the checkbox (checked or not).

I need to manipulate the state of the check box too, but this was easy.

I'm using the following code:

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "injection");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            webView.loadUrl(
                    "javascript:(function() { " +
                            "var ch=document.getElementById('myCheckBox');" +
                            "ch.checked=false; " + //This works!!!
                            "injection.reportCheckboxState('111111');" + //This works too
                            "function myFunction() {" +
                            "  injection.reportCheckboxState('222222'); " +
                            "}"+
                            "ch.onClick=myFunction;"+
                            //"ch.addEventListener(\"onClick\", myFunction);"+
                            "})()"
            );
        }


    @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            boolean returnVal = false;
            if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("/doSomething.htm")) {
                //I can intercept the onClick event on this checkbox, but I don't know how to read the value of the checkbox here


            } else {
                returnVal = true;
            }
            return returnVal;
        }
    });


    private class JsObject {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void reportCheckboxState(String string) {
        Log.d(TAG, "" + string);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to inject some Javascript into this HTML form. The first lines of the code are working right:

```
"var ch=document.getElementById('myCheckBox');" +
                            "ch.checked=false; " +
                            "injection.reportCheckboxState('111111');"
```

I receive in my android log console the string "111111". And the ch.cheched=false works too.

But I'm unable to instruct the checkbox that it should call the injection.reportCheckboxState method on "onClick" event (when the user touches the checkbox)".

Can anybody help me? Is it possible to do this?

Thanks ind advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you let the `WebView` report javascript console messages in the android log (at least in debug versions), this way you will se if there is any error or warning on the page easy (you could also use the inspector in chrome on newer versions of android).

To get the javascript logs into your android log you have to override the `onConsoleMessage` in the `WebViews` `WebChromeClient`, which is done like this (API level 7+):

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
  @Override
  public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "" + consoleMessage.message());
    return super.onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage);
  }
});
```

By just looking at the JavaScript code in your snippet, I can't see anything that I wrong (but I might be wrong there, hehe), but the JavaScript logs will most likely tell you what it is that is broken.

---

*Edit.*

After another look at your JS code, it seems that your `onClick` method might be misspelled, it should be `onclick` (lowercase).
Still, the logging recommendation still applies!

Comment: I'm already logging the console messages and no strange messages are logged. And I tried with onclick on lowercase and it does not work too :S

Comment: Changing the event name to `onclick` makes the JavaScript valid, so the error is not in the javascript in that case. What happens if you remove the initial `onchange="location.href='/doSomething.html'"` event?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with another aproach. All the suggested did not work

Unfortunatelly, I'm not the owner of the site and I'm not  authorized to change the original html.

Now, I download the html with an asynctask, and after that I change the "onchange" event of the checkbox:

```
//Replace the onchange from the checkbox with our method
String html=downloadthehtmlwithanasynctask
    html = html.replace("location.href='/doSomething.html'", "injection.reportCheckboxState(this.checked)");
```

And I load this html into the webview and inject my javascript interface:

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "injection");
(...)
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

And now it works! Thank you for your help.